# I would have gone some pages counted

Tags: page-numbering

I use two side `book` document class. I have a problem with page numbering. I would have gone some pages counted and I do not actually want it to be counted as part of the book.there are some one side page.I want every paper of them get only one number,mean it to be counted one time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Shall only the printing be suspended or even the counting?

Comment: counting please.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

This uses the `\SuspendCounters` feature of (my) package `assoccnt`, which prevents specific counters to be increased until `\ResumeSuspendedCounters` is used.

I additionally 'killed' the page number formatting to prevent the page numbers to appear.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[globalsuspend=true]{assoccnt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

\blindtext[20]

\clearpage
\SuspendCounters{page}
\let\thepageorig\thepage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\chapter{Second}


\blindtext[20]

\ResumeSuspendedCounters%
\let\thepage\thepageorig

\chapter{Third}

\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

**Edit -- Now the 'same' document without suspending the page counter**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

\blindtext[20]

\clearpage
\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[20]
\chapter{Third}

\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now without suspension -- Chapter 2 is used with page number 9

[image]