# Page number problem in chapters of my thesis, how to make chapter title page with no page number?

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

I am working with my thesis. I want all my  chapter title should be in single page and in page centered and my first section introduction start on new page, by doing this my chapter title page also got the page number . I want to make my title page without page number and number continue from the introduction. same for my all chapters.
I am using this

```
% Chapter 2
\begin{center}
\setstretch{2}
\chapter{chapter title here} % Write in your own chapter title
\label{Chapter2}
\lhead{Chapter 2. \emph{chapter title here}} % Write in your own chapter title to set the page header
\end{center}
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
```

In this chapter, we have

Comment: You could try writing `\thispagestyle{empty}` in your chapter page.

Comment: Sounds as if you should use `\part` and `\chapter` instead of `\chapter` and `\section`. And that you should learn how to correctly setup page styles.

Comment: i tried  \thispagestyle{empty} by doing this page number is eliminated from the page. but still counting page number.

Comment: @DINESHMITTAL: You want to 'forget' the section page for pagenumbering, i.e, say   page 5, `\section{something} `, next page is 6 then, not 7?

Comment: @DINESHMITTAL I think you have to add `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` in your chapter page, together with `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: my first chapter end at page no 34. then on next page my chapter 2 title page. and on next page first section of my chapter. i want page no 35  on first section page. but its 36 because 35 page no given to title page of chapter 2....

Comment: I've done something similar: See my answer to `non-counting` pages question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244299/i-would-have-gone-some-pages-counted.

Comment: i am not able to download \usepackage{assoccnt} with miktek 2.9 package manager. what should i do

Comment: @DINESHMITTAL: Sorry, I don't use miktex at all, but `assoccnt` is on CTAN too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the commands I wrote in the comments and it worked:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{34}
End of first chapter

\begin{center}
\setstretch{2}
\chapter{chapter title here} % Write in your own chapter title
\thispagestyle{empty} % Remove page number
\addtocounter{page}{-1} % Substract 1 from page number
\label{Chapter2}
\lhead{Chapter 2. \emph{chapter title here}} % Write in your own chapter title to set the page header
\end{center}
\clearpage
\section{Introduction}
In this chapter we have...

\end{document}
```

You could use this code in your thesis file and see if it works fine.